# Is it ok to say "A task visual consists of the following elements"?

Tags: word-usage

I want to express the following idea in a requirements document: a visual element is composed from a set of sub-elements, such as title, date box, shape and so on.

Is it all right to say :

> The visual element consists of the following elements:
>
> - title
> - date box
> - shape" ?

Comment: Alright, except you are using 'element' twice in the same sentence. Unless you can think of anything better I would change the second into *sub-elements*.

Comment: @WS2: excellent comment, thank you. Please create a answer so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, except you are using 'element' twice in the same sentence.

Unless you can think of anything better I would change the second into ***sub-elements***.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with the grammar. The repetition of elements is unpleasant though.

Some alternatives:

> The visual element consists of the following components:
>
> The visual element consists of the following constituents:
>
> The visual element consists of the following aspects:
>
> The visual element consists of the following ingredients: